# IntelliJ TypeScript plugin complains that "window is not defined" in React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, react-dom

IntelliJ's TypeScript plugin complains that `window` is not defined in my .tsx file on a React project, but seems to be compiling just fine.

How do I get IntelliJ to stop complaining about DOM env definitions?

Comment: Can you post the whole error please?

Comment: code snippet that shows up the issue as well as the error screenshot would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an ESLint error, not related to TypeScript plugin. Solved by adding `browser: true` to "env" segment of `.eslintrc.json`:

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    env: {
        browser: true,
        node: true
    }
};
```